# Prove that if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|a-b|\lt 5$, then $|b|\lt|a|+5.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic, absolute-value

I'm trying to prove that if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|a-b|\lt 5$, then $|b|\lt|a|+5.$

I've first written down $-5\lt a-b \lt5$ and have tried to add different things from all sides of the inequality. Like adding $b+5$ to get $b\lt a+5 \lt 10+b$ but am just not seeing where that gets me.

Comment: With regard to your misgivings about the occurrence of $\leq$ rather than strict $<$ in some answers: if $x \leq z < y$ then $x<y$. In fact if $x \leq p \leq q \leq r < s \leq t \leq u \leq v \leq y$ then $x<y$. In other words, in a chain of inequalities, if at least _one_ of the inequalities is strict then the inequality of the two endpoints is strict.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Some general properties of the absolute value

First let [me](https://books.google.de/books?id=hzUh1M56C3EC&pg=PT24&dq=Absolute%20value%20rudin&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oNmSVYbyAszaUcb-gbAD&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Absolute%20value%20rudin&f=false) [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Real_numbers) [that](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsoluteValue.html)
$$ |x| :=\begin{cases}x & \text{if }x \geq 0,\\ -x & \text{if }x <0.\end{cases}$$

We show that $|x|=|-x|$ for every $x\in \Bbb R$:

- If $x\geq 0$ then $|x| = x$ and $|-x|= -(-x)=x$.
- If $x< 0$ then $|x| = -x$ and $|-x|= -x$.

$$ \rightarrow \qquad \boxed{\quad |x|=|-x| \qquad \phantom\int\forall x \in \Bbb R\quad} \tag{1}$$

Now, we show that $x\leq |x|$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$:

- If $x\geq 0$, then $|x| = x$ and so $x\leq |x|$.
- If $x< 0$, then $|x| = -x$ and so $x <0 < -x = |x|$.

$$ \rightarrow \qquad \boxed{\quad x\leq |x| \qquad\phantom\int \forall x \in \Bbb R\quad }\tag{2}$$

As consequence of $(1)$ and $(2)$ for any $x\in\Bbb R$, we get

$$ -x \overset{(2)}{\leq} |-x| \overset{(1)}{=} |x|.$$

$$ \rightarrow \qquad \boxed{\quad-x\leq |x| \qquad\phantom\int \forall x \in \Bbb R \quad}\tag{3}$$

The last tool we need is that for every $x\in \Bbb R$ and every $t> 0$, if $|x|<t$ then $x<t$:

- If $x \geq 0$, then $|x|=x$ and thus $x=|x|<t$.
- If $x<0$, then $x<0< t$.

$$ \rightarrow \qquad \boxed{\quad\forall x \in \Bbb R \ \text{ and }\  \forall t> 0:\phantom\int |x|<t \implies x<t\quad }\tag{4}$$

### The proof you want:

Now suppose that $a,b\in \Bbb R$ are such that $|a-b|< 5$. Then we have the following relations:

$$|a-b|< 5 \overset{(4)}{\implies} a-b<5 \overset{(*)}{\implies} -b<5-a=5+(-a) \overset{(3)}{\leq} 5+|a|  $$

and thus $-b<5+|a|$ (for step $(*)$, subtract $a$ from both sides of the inequality). Moreover,

$$|a-b|< 5 \overset{(1)}{\implies} |b-a|<5 \overset{(4)}{\implies} b-a<5 \overset{(**)}{\implies} b< 5+a \overset{(2)}{\leq}5+|a|$$

and thus $b< 5 +|a|$ (for step $(**)$, add $a$ to both sides of the inequality). Finally

$$-b<5+|a| \quad\text{ and }\quad b< 5 +|a| \qquad\implies\qquad |b|<5+|a|$$
(because either $|b|=b$ or $|b| =-b$).

### Generalizaion:

$$ \boxed{\quad\forall a,b \in \Bbb R \ \text{ and }\  \forall t>0:\phantom\int |a-b|<t \implies |b|<t+|a|\quad }$$

*Proof 1:* Replace $5$ by $t$ in the proof above.

*Proof 2:* We can also use the triangle inequality as already suggested by the other answers above.

We show that $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$ for every $x,y\in\Bbb R$:
We have
$$ x+y \overset{(2)}{\leq} |x|+y \overset{(2)}{\leq} |x|+|y|\qquad
\text{and}\qquad-(x+y)=(-x)+(-y) \overset{(3)}{\leq} |x|+(-y) \overset{(3)}{\leq} |x|+|y|.$$
$$ \rightarrow\qquad\boxed{\quad \phantom\int |x+y|\leq |x|+|y| \qquad\forall x,y \in \Bbb R\quad }\tag{5}$$
It follows that
$$|b| =|a+(b-a)| \overset{(5)}{\leq} |a|+|b-a| \overset{(***)}{<} |a|+t,$$
where we have used that $|b-a|\overset{(1)}{=}|a-b|<t$ for step $(***)$.

Comment: Great example of really utilizing proper definitions and concepts that build up on each other and eventually culminating to a simple to follow proof :)

Comment: Note that we did **not** need the **reverse** triangle inequality explicitly in *Proof 2* of the generalization (but only a half of its proof).

Comment: This answer does contain enough detail.

Answer (score 7):

Hint:

Use the reverse triangle inequality:

$$||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|~\forall~x,y\in\Bbb{R}$$

Comment: I did see that in my book, but the $\le$ sign instead of the $\lt$ in my particular problem, steered me away. And wasnt sure if it was still applicable in this case as i dont really understand it that well yet.

Comment: @ChurningButter, $\leq$ just implies that there is the equality case. Since you want strict inequality $\lt$, you can do that simply by loosening the bounds.

Comment: @ChurningButter, let me give you another hint: $$||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|\lt 5\implies |a|-|b|\in (-5,5)$$

Comment: So $||a|-|b||\lt 5$?

Comment: @ChurningButter, yes, so you have,$$||a|-|b||\lt 5\implies |a|-|b|\in (-5,5)\implies |b|-|a|\in (-5,5)$$

Comment: I'm sure you can do the rest.

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark beside my answer. :)

Comment: Any further hints? Still stuck on this one!

Comment: @ChurningButter, I'm not sure how much more detailed solution do you need. Can you point out exactly which part you can't understand? That way, I can help you better.

Comment: @ChurningButter, Didn't my last comment (hint) already give you the answer?
 
$$|b|-|a|\in (-5,5)\implies |b|\in (-5+|a|,5+|a|)\implies |b|\lt 5+|a|=|a|+5$$
 
I'm not sure how much "simpler" can I explain this...

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $|b|=|b+a-a|=|(a)+(b-a)|$. Now use the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 4):

If this exercise was intended to be solved without the triangle inequality,

If $|a - b| \lt 5$ then by isolating $b$ you will get that $ a - 5 \lt b \lt a + 5 $ and then multiplying by $-1$ you get $ -a -5 \lt -b \lt 5 - a $.

So you can draw out $ b \lt a + 5$ and $ -b \lt 5 - a $. So combining these last two inequalities,

$$| b| \lt \max\{ 5 - a, 5 + a \} \tag{1}$$

Now use the fact that $ a \le |a| \;\ \text{and} -a \le |a| $ to obtain the desired result. result

Answer (score 3):

If $|a-b|<5$, then $|b|=|b-a+a|\le |b-a|+|a| < 5+|a|$. That's it!

Comment: *Slow applause*

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this gives a different point of view.  Start by supposing that, to the contrary, $|b| > |a| + 5 $.  We then want to show that this implies $|a - b | > 5$.
Just go case by case.

Case I: $b > 0, a > 0$.
Then the assumption implies $b > a + 5$ which implies $b - a > 5$ which implies 
$|b - a| > 5$ as desired.

Case II.  $b < 0, a < 0$.
The assumption implies $-b > -a + 5$ which implies $a - b > 5$ so again $|a - b| > 5$

Case III.  $b > 0, a < 0$
The assumption implies $b > -a + 5$.  Add $-a$ (a positive quantity) to both sides to get $b - a > -a + 5$ which implies $|b - a| > -2a + 5 > 5$ as desired.

Case IV.  $b < 0, a > 0$.
The assumption implies $-b > a + 5$.  Add $a$ (a positive quantity) to both sides to get $a - b > 2a + 5$ which implies $|a -b| > 2a + 5 > 5$ as desired.

The cases where either (or both) are $0$ are trivial.

Answer (score 0):

$$||a|-|b||\leq|a-b|<5$$

by the reverse triangle inequality.

$$|b|-|a|\leq||a|-|b||<5$$

Because $-x \leq |x|$ for all $x$.

$$|b|-|a|<5$$

$$|b|<5+|a|$$

Answer (score 0):

We will use reverse triangle inequality i.e. $||a|-|b|| \le |a-b|$ and what you got, that $|a-b|<5 \implies -5<a-b<5$

Note : $x\le y<z \implies x<z$ because if the equality holds and $x=y$ then too $x<z$.
$$|a-b|<5
\\ \implies ||a|-|b|| \le |a-b| <5  
\\ \implies ||a|-|b|| < 5
\\ \implies -5 < |a|-|b|
\\ \implies |b| < |a|+5$$

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the inequality is **NOT** 'implied and implied by' ($\iff$). This means that just because we have:

$$|a-b|\lt5\implies |b|\lt|a|+5$$
this doesn't mean that:

$$|b|\lt|a|+5 \implies |a-b|\lt5$$

as a global truth is true, in fact it is false, for example let $a=4, b=-3$.

We can see that the first condition is necessarily true from a diagram:

[image: logical regions]

The green regions
shows the area for which $|a-b|\lt5$, and the orange regions show for which regions $|b|\ge|a|+5$ (except for they both use solid lines - you have to imagine the boundaries as open or closed!).

The white regions are therefore regions where $|b|\lt|a|+5$ but $|a-b|\ge5$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $$|a-b| \leq 5$$

It stands that $$||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b| \\ \Rightarrow -|a-b| \leq |a|-|b| \leq |a-b|$$

From the inequalities $-|a-b| \leq |a|-|b|$ and $|a-b| \leq 5$ we get $$|b|-|a| \leq |a-b| \leq 5 \Rightarrow |b|-|a| \leq 5 \Rightarrow |b| \leq |a|+5$$

Comment: Note, the desired inequality is strict. You only obtain a weak inequality.